# Best way to insert ~20 million rows using Python/MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I need to store a defaultdict object containing ~20M objects into a database. The dictionary maps a string to a string, so the table has two columns, no primary key because it's constructed later.

Things I've tried:

- executemany, passing in the set of keys and values in the dictionary. Works well when number of values < ~1M.
- Executing single statements. Works, but slow.
- Using transactions

  ```
  con = sqlutils.getconnection()
  cur = con.cursor()
  print len(self.table)

  cur.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;")
  cur.execute("SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;")
  cur.execute("SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;")
  i = 0
  for k in self.table:
      cur.execute("INSERT INTO " + sqlutils.gettablename(self.sequence) + " (key, matches) values (%s, %s);", (k, str(self.hashtable[k])))
      i += 1
      if i % 10000 == 0:
          print i
  #cur.executemany("INSERT INTO " + sqlutils.gettablename(self.sequence) + " (key, matches) values (%s, %s)", [(k, str(self.table[k])) for k in self.table])

  cur.execute("SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;")
  cur.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;")
  cur.execute("COMMIT")
  con.commit()
  cur.close()
  con.close()

  print "Finished", self.sequence, "in %.3f sec" % (time.time() - t)
  ```

This is a recent conversion from SQLite to MySQL. Oddly enough, I'm getting much better performance when I use SQLite (30s to insert 3M rows in SQLite, 480s in MySQL). Unfortunately, MySQL is a necessity because the project will be scaled up in the future.

-

### Edit

Using LOAD DATA INFILE works like a charm. Thanks to all who helped! Inserting 3.2M rows takes me ~25s.

Comment: Yes, when you dont have to worry about MVCC, things are much faster. How big is your innodb_log_buffer_size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can inserts multiple values with one query: `INSERT INTO table (key1, key2) VALUES ("value_key1", "value_key2"), ("another_value_key1", "another_value_key2"), ("and_again", "and_again...");`

Also, you could try to write your datas inside a file and use [`LOAD DATA` from Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) that is designed to insert with "very hight speed" (dixit Mysql).

I dunno if "file writing" + "MySQL Load Data" will be faster than Insert multiple values in one query (or many queries if MySQL has a limit for it)

It depends on your hardware (write a file is "fast" with a SSD), on your file system configuration, on MySQL configuration etc. So, you have to test on your "prod" env to see what solution is the fastest for you.

Comment: My guess is that writing a file and loading it would be faster than a connection from Python.  The OP can try and report back.

Comment: I've decided to go with dumping the values into a CSV first, then loading it to the DB. Seems like it works the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Insert of directly inserting, generate a sql file (using [extended inserts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert) etc) then fetch this to MySQL, this will save you quite a lot of overhead.

NB : you'll still save some execution time if you avoid recomputing constant values in your loop, ie:

```
for k in self.table:
    xxx = sqlutils.gettablename(self.sequence)
    do_something_with(xxx, k)
```

=>

```
xxx = sqlutils.gettablename(self.sequence)
for k in self.table:
    do_something_with(xxx, k)
```